# Nodejs how to wait until function will finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to save a user in mongodb and after read a saved attribute "usageAcceptance". It should work from the first usage

My algorithmus:

1. Im checking if user is in a database
2. YES Im saving this user with attribute "usageAcceptance" as false
3. NO Im doing nothing go to WelcomeCheck function check
4. getCurrentUser().usageAcceptance which is undefined when I start my program for a first time. After that it works

Problem:
I think here is a problem:

```
setCurrentUser(usr);
```

What to do to be sure that JS execute this command. Because after setting user I'm getting one attribute from it getCurrentUser().usageAcceptance. So my code works but only after second usage. It seems that JS saves my user too slow or not setting my user in a property time. How to be sure that I saved user and after set that method?

My code:

```
        let usr: User = handler.state.session.user;
            usr = new userModel();
            usr.alexaUserId = sessionUser.userId;
            usr.amazonUserId = profile.user_id;
            usr.name = profile.name;
            userModel.findOne({"amazonUserId": profile.user_id}, (err, doc) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error: ", err);
                }
                // in case we don't find the user in our database we continue anyways as we will be lead to the newSession Handler

                if (doc) {
                    console.log("User already in Database: ");

                }
                if (!doc) {
                    // I want that new user has always this attribute as false:
                    usr.usageAcceptance = false;
                    usr.save(err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error:", err.message);
                        } else {

                            console.log("Saved user in mongoDB.");
                        }

                    });

                }

            });
            //here is an error :(
            setCurrentUser(usr);


        "WelcomeCheck": function () {
        console.log(getCurrentUser().usageAcceptance);

        if (getCurrentUser().usageAcceptance == false && getCurrentUser().usageAcceptance != undefined) {
            this.emit(":ask", "Please accept our intern policy if you want to use this app. Please say yes if you accept it!");

        }
        else {
            this.emit("Welcome");

        }


    }
```

Comment: I think you need to `setCurrentUser` inside the `findOne` callback

Comment: Jaromanda where exactly?

Comment: before the `});`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'usageAcceptance' of undefined
:(

Comment: sorry, I didn't see all of the code for some reason - the "duplicate" should help in some way, because the problem is that you are dealing with asynchronous code in a synchronous manner